# How to match an array of objects with sinon.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sinon

How can I match an array of results in a sinon matcher?

For example, how can this code work?

```
var mystub = sinon.stub();
var myarg = { val: 1, mylist: [ {a:1}, {b:2}, {c:3,d:4} ] };

mystub(myarg);

sinon.assert.calledOnce(mystub).withArgs(
  sinon.match({val: 1, mylist: [{a:1},{b:2},{c:3,d:4}]}) // this doesn't work
);
```

How can I get this to work? (Note that in my test, I don't have access to myarg - so I need to match it).

Obviously, I could write a custom function matcher, but I'm looking for something a bit easier to read and write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The custom matching function in the accepted answer is useful to know about but total overkill for this simple use case. To build on [the useful answer from Eryk Warren](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53241409), how about this:

```
// match each element of the actual array against the corresponding entry in the expected array
sinon.assert.match(actual, expected.map(sinon.match));
```

Answer (score 14):

*This is an old posting, but I couldn't find the right answer for this question.*

Sinon supports nested matchers. So to test the matching of deep object, you can do the following:

```
const mystub = sinon.stub();
const myarg = {
  val: 1,
  mylist: [{ a: 1, x: 'foo' }, { b: 2, y: 'bar' }, { c: 3, d: 4, e: 5 } ],
};

mystub(myarg);

sinon.assert.calledOnce(mystub);
sinon.assert.calledWithMatch(mystub, {
  val: 1,
  mylist: [
    sinon.match({ a: 1 }),
    sinon.match({ b: 2 }),
    sinon.match({ c: 3, d: 4 }),
  ],
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Custom matcher.

I recommend writing your own custom [sinon matcher](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#matchers).

You can write it in a way that it is general and easy to read when it gets used.

Here is an example approach:

```
// usage
...withArgs(sinon.match(deepMatch({
    val: 1,
    mylist: [{a:1}, {b:2}, {c:3,d:4}]
})));


// custom matcher
const deepMatch = (expectation) => (actual) => {
    return Object.keys(expectation).every(key => {
        if (checkIfItsObject(expectation[key])) {
            // value is also an object, go deeper and then compare etc.
        } else {
            // compare and return boolean value accordingly
        }
    });
};

// note: checkIfItsObject is pseudocode - there are many ways to
// check if an object is an object so I did not want to complicate
// this code example here
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what I ended up doing.  Seems like this would be a common need. I'm surprised it's not part of sinon.

Answer (score 1):

Sinon has matchers on the content of arrays, for example, [`sinon.match.array.deepEquals`](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/matchers/#sinonmatcharraydeepequalsarr)

This works:

```js
var mystub = sinon.stub();

var myarg = { val: 1, mylist: [ {a:1}, {b:2}, {c:3,d:4} ] };

mystub(myarg);

sinon.assert.calledWith(mystub,
  sinon.match({
    val: 1,
    mylist: sinon.match.array.deepEquals([ {a:1}, {b:2}, {c:3,d:4} ])
  })
);
```

Comment: It works! In my case, I should also have checked for adding new props: `sinon.assert.calledWithMatch(func, sinon.match.every(sinon.match.hasOwn('property')));`